# Private NuGet Package won't install due to version

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I am using the NuGet Package Explorer to package an internal library which is then published to our private NuGet Feed.  The package is very simple in that it only contains a single assembly and the pdb file for said assembly.  The assembly was built in .NET 4.5 and I am trying to install the package into a project that also targets 4.5.

The error I am getting is:

> You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Package explorer looks like the below image:
[image]

For those of you not familiar with package explorer, the markup of the nuspec looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I'm having the same issue and it's driving me nuts...